# NJ Transit Train first time riding

Tags: trains, public-transport

I've never taken a train anywhere before and need to take an NJ Transit train by myself tomorrow.  How do you navigate the train station and find the train number to make sure you get on the right train?

Comment: Which Train station?  And how about simply by looking at the board to see which train is on a given platform.

Comment: Smaller stations are, of course, simpler.  Mostly there will be one platform for the "towards NYC" direction and one for the "away from NYC" direction.  The platforms will generally be labeled.  As a last resort, if you are still nervous when you're getting on the train, ask the conductor or other train crew whether your train will get you to your destination.  If you have to change trains, for example at Secaucus, the crew will tell you this.

Answer (score 3):

Details vary depending on which station(s) you'll be using. In general, trains are announced on video screens and/or by audio announcements. Video screens are more common at larger stations and list the next several upcoming trains with arrival time, line name and track number. Audio announcements indicate a track number, train number, and time until arrival. At larger stations there may be staff available who can help.

Schedules are posted, in case you're not sure of the exact time or train number. There's also extensive information at the [NJ Transit web site](http://www.njtransit.com/) and numerous mobile apps that will help (search on "NJ Transit").

If you're nervous about it, I suggest NJ Transit's [How to ride NJ Transit](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=HowToRideTo) page. Their [Station and Parking Information](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=StationParkRideTo) page also includes diagrams of stations and other details that may help.

Comment: There's actually a "How to Ride a Train" page!  Only in America...

Comment: @jpatokal In fairness, while it's true that [common sense](http://www.metro.net/riding/safety-security/boarding-and-exiting/) should need no guide, there is a lot of variation in how transit operates around the U.S. You can buy a ticket on board Metro-North, but not Tri-Rail. Food & drink is allowed on the T, restricted on SEPTA, banned by WMATA. In Seattle, until a few years ago, you paid your fare when exiting inbound buses but when boarding outbound buses. So overall, it's not a bad idea to learn "how to ride" each new system you encounter, even if you are experienced with transit.

Comment: @jpatokal that's because in other countries this information requires more than one page.  See, for example, http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/about-your-trip, which links to six other pages: *Journey planner, To and from Schiphol, Taking the train at night, To and from the station, Facilities at the station,* and *Travelling Conditions.*